# How to parse "text" from span class with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I want to parse the text in span class with Jsoup.
Here is my Html code portion.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
<div class = "abcd">
<span> This is text </span>
</div>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrote something like that

```
Element element =  doc.select("div.abcd > span");
System.out.println("Text = "+element.text());
```

This isn't working. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: just tested you code and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `"div.abcd > span"`

to

`"div.abcd span"`

Comment: @YassirArafatRoni mark as answer if my answer solve your problem. Thanks.